# is the functor of finite order elements in grp representable

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, representable-functors

My question is whether the functor F:Grp->Set that sends a Group to its Set of elements with finite order is representable.
I have the sense that it shouldn't be but I've so far failed to prove it in any way.

Comment: Does it preserve infinite products?

Comment: It is not (as Keith alludes to, it preserves finite limits but not infinite limits); however, it is a filtered colimit of representable functors $\text{colim}_n \text{ Hom}(C_n, G)$, which has some of the same nice properties. See https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/06/23/operations-pro-objects-and-grothendiecks-galois-theory/. It is in some sense represented by the profinite integers $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, not as a group, but as a pro-group.